# getDerivedStateFromProps no showing any changes on my form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hey guys I am having issues with editing my populated Edit Agent Form. I am using the getDerivedStateFromProps() life cycle method but each time I try to edit the after it has been fully populated I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. I have gone through the react documentation severally but no solution with all the methods I have used so far. Please How do I resolve this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TextField from '../../commons/TextField.jsx';
import SubmitButton from '../../commons/SubmitButton.jsx';
import fetchSingleAgent from '../../../actions/getSingleAgentAction';
import updateAgentInput from '../../../middleware/updateAgentInput';

class EditAgentForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent._id: '',
            phoneNumber: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.phoneNumber: '',
            password: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.password: '',
            fullname: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.fullname: '',
            address: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.address: '',
            bvn: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.bvn: '',
            email: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.email: '',
            age: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.age: '',
            meansOfId: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.meansOfId: 'sample',
            guarantorsFullName: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.guarantorsFullName: '',
            guarantorsPhonenumber: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.guarantorsPhonenumber: '',
            guarantorsAddress: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.guarantorsAddress: '',
            idNumber: this.props.singleAgent ? this.props.singleAgent.idNumber: '',
            errors: {},
            isLoading: false,
        }
        this.onEditAgent = this.onEditAgent.bind(this);
    }

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} nextProps
   * @returns {*} - single master agent object
   */
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log('===>', props.singleAgent._id, state.id);
    if (props.singleAgent._id == state.id) {
        return null
    }

    return {
        id: props.singleAgent._id,
        phoneNumber: props.singleAgent.phoneNumber,
        password: props.singleAgent.password,
        fullname: props.singleAgent.fullname,
        address: props.singleAgent.address,
        bvn: props.singleAgent.bvn,
        email: props.singleAgent.email,
        age: props.singleAgent.age,
        meansOfId: props.singleAgent.meansOfId,
        guarantorsFullName: props.singleAgent.guarantorsFullName,
        guarantorsPhonenumber: props.singleAgent.guarantorsPhonenumber,
        guarantorsAddress: props.singleAgent.guarantorsAddress,
        isNumber: props.singleAgent.isNumber,
    };
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @returns {*} - state
   */
  onChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      });
  }
  /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @returns {*} - state
   */
  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('I got here 2')
    if (this.isValid()) {
      console.log('I got here')
      this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
    }
  }

  onEditAgent(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({isLoading: true})
  }

  isValid() {
    console.log('I got here 3')
    const { errors, isValid } = updateAgentInput(this.state);
    if (!isValid) {
      this.setState({ errors });
    }
    return isValid;
  }
    render() {
        const {
            phoneNumber,
            password,
            fullname,
            address,
            bvn,
            email,
            age,
            meansOfId,
            guarantorsFullName,
            guarantorsPhonenumber,
            guarantorsAddress,
            idNumber,
            errors,
            isLoading,
        } = this.state;
        const meansOfIdentificationList = ['Select', 'voters card','international passport','national id card','drivers license']
        const editAgentForm = (
            <div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Update Agents Form</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Fullname</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.fullname}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={fullname || ''}
                          field="fullname"
                          type="text"
                          className="myfullname"
                          placeholder="Enter Fullname"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.phoneNumber}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={phoneNumber || ''}
                          field="phoneNumber"
                          type="text"
                          className="form-control"
                          placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.email}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={email || ''}
                          field="email"
                          type="email"
                          className="myemail"
                          placeholder="Enter Email"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.address}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={address || ''}
                          field="address"
                          type="text"
                          className="myaddress"
                          placeholder="Enter Your Address"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.age}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={age || ''}
                          field="age"
                          type="text"
                          className="myage"
                          placeholder="Enter Age"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>BVN</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.bvn}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={bvn || ''}
                          field="bvn"
                          type="password"
                          className="mybvn"
                          placeholder="Enter your BVN"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Password</label>
                        <TextField
                          error={errors.password}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          value={password || ''}
                          field="password"
                          type="text"
                          className="mypassword"
                          placeholder="Enter Your Password"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Guarantor Address</label>
                    <TextField
                      error={errors.guarantorsAddress}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={guarantorsAddress}
                      field="guarantorsAddress"
                      type="text"
                      className="myguarantorAddress"
                      placeholder="Enter Guarantor Address"
                    />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Guarantor Fullname</label>
                    <TextField
                      error={errors.guarantorsFullName}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={guarantorsFullName}
                      field="guarantorsFullName"
                      type="text"
                      className="myguarantorFullname"
                      placeholder="Enter Guarantor Fullname"
                    />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Guarantor Phone Number</label>
                    <TextField
                      error={errors.guarantorsPhonenumber}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={guarantorsPhonenumber}
                      field="guarantorsPhonenumber"
                      type="text"
                      className="myguarantorPhonenumber"
                      placeholder="Enter Guarantor Phonenumber"
                    />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Identification Number</label>
                    <TextField
                      error={errors.idNumber}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={idNumber}
                      field="idNumber"
                      type="text"
                      className="myidNumber"
                      placeholder="Enter Identification Number"
                    />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Select Means of Identification </label>
                     <select
                       className="form-control select2"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       name="meansOfId"
                       value={meansOfId}
                     >
                       {
                              meansOfIdentificationList.map(idMeans => (
                                <option value={idMeans}>
                                  {idMeans}
                                </option>
                              ))
                          }
                     </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                      <SubmitButton
                        type="submit"
                        className="mybutton"
                        onClick={this.onSubmit}
                        label="Update Agent"
                      />
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        )
        return <div>{editAgentForm}</div>
    }
}

EditAgentForm.propTypes = {
    singleAgent: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      singleAgent: state.singleAgentRequests.singleAgent
    };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSingleAgent })(EditAgentForm);
```

"I expected the populated form output to change but each time I try to edit it I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined."

Answer (score 0):

In constructor, you need to bind all function(which contain `this` parameter). Since you did not bind these function, you get error setState of undefined. Because `this` parameter is undefined.

Comment: Thanks alot. I totally forgot to bind my functions. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your methods to arrow functions, so instead of `onSubmit() {}` you would use `onSubmit = () => {}`, we do this so we don't have to bind `this` explicitly in the constructor.

The reason why this works is because arrow functions lexically bind their context (where it appears in code) so this actually refers to the originating context, ie our class instance.

Comment: No problem, be sure to accept an answer and upvote any that were helpful